# How to use radio button with dynamic list view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, radio-button, odbc

I am trying to make an online test system, where questions and options are added from database to list view. plz tell me how can i use radio button to check if question was correct or not.
this is the code i am using:-

```
<asp:listview ID="Listview1" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
<ul class="row" style="list-style:none;">
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
</ul>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<li>
<div class="row1">
Q. <%#Eval("question") %>><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1 runat="server" /><%#Eval("op1") %>>
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" /><%#Eval("op2") %>>
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" /><%#Eval("op3") %>>
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" /><%#Eval("op4") %>>
</div>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:listview>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading the options dinamically, you have to get the values using `Request["RadioButton1"]` for example, after the postback